# Calling and wrapping C function in Nodejs (Emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten

I'm new to emscripten and web development.

Recently, I'm trying to build a node.js module based on C library.
I'm testing with a simple function like `int add(int a, int b)`.
I use `MODULARIZE` to compile the C library to let it pass the module as a wrapped promise function instead of global Modules.

I can call the function in javascript with `ccall` method like how the emscripten document stated.

```
factory().then(instance => {
   instance.ccall('add', 'number', ['number', 'number'], [1, 1]);
});
```

But how can I wrap the function in a way that lets me call the function without dealing with Promises?
eg.

```
let sum = add(1, 2);
// sum = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a standalone wasm binary and then use `WebAssembly.Instance` to act as a wrapper.
First create a **c** file with no main.

```
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

**NOTE**: You have to use EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE before every function you want to export.
Then compile to standalone wasm using

```
$ emcc {Path to your c file } -o {The name of stand alone wasm} --no-entry
```

**NOTE**: You have to write extension in file names.

For example `$ emcc abc.c -o xyz.wasm --no-entry` should generate a single xyz.wasm and nothing else.

Now in your JS file, you can do

```
const readFileSync = require('fs').readFileSync;
const wasm_module = new WebAssembly.Instance(new 
WebAssembly.Module(readFileSync(**{Path to the .wasm file you generated}**)));
```

Then all or your exported functions will be available in `wasm_module.exports`, so you can do something like

```
const add = wasm_module.exports.add;
let sum = add(1, 2);
// sum = 3
```

#### UPDATE

Now node supports experimantal wasm modules. So instead of that long JS code you can just import it from **.wasm** file directly, like:

```js
import * from '**{Path to .wasm file you generated}**' as wasm_module;
let sum = wasm_module.add(1, 2);
// sum = 3
```

**NOTE**: This feature is *experimental* so you will need to enable it explicitly. i.e. Instead of `$ node script.js`, use `$ --experimental-wasm-modules script.js`.

Comment: Can the .wasm file path to be passed into `readFileSync()` a relative path? Or it should be an absolute path? I'm encountering file not found when passing it as a relative path.

Comment: I've tried to pass it as an absolute path. And it has the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` now.

Comment: @Steven        **It does not matter whether path is absolute or relative.** It should still work. Could you please give more information about your file directory and the argument you are passing to `readFileSync` and the command you are using to compile **c**. _I have tryed it on my system and its works fine._

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make Fibonacci example from https://gist.github.com/surma/b2705b6cca29357ebea1c9e6e15684cc to work on nodejs using using this example (just couldn't use `as wasm_module` part). See `test.mjs` file:
```
import {fib} from './2c0a4e42c09253f6c8b000c266e1ab77.wasm';
console.log(fib(2));
```
My `node --version -> v14.17.6`